# Translate Code from VBA (Word) to Javascript/ JScript don't work

Tags: javascript, ms-word, jscript, activexobject

I need help. I use an Mail Merge in word and I want to translate the vba code to JScript or Javascript. But the problem is that the function is not method it is a property.

Here my vba code:

```
Sub test()

With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
    .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
    .SupressBlankLines = True
    With .DataSource 
             .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
             .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

I translate it to the following code but it don't work:

```
var objWord; 
objWord.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.Destination("wdSendToNewDocument") \\.... but it don't work
```

Do you have any idea to solve the code problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: Because I need this for an automation that runs with JScript

Comment: Do you have an idea?

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! Could you please provide us some more details about the any error message? "it don't works" is not a good explanation of the error.

Comment: Is this a JScript automation *within Word* or in some other VBA script running outside?  If it's within Word I would expect the ActiveDocument object to be somehow available.  If it's external I would expect you to have to instantiate the Word object yourself.